# how to create category drop down and show list of posts related to that category with thumbnail in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, posts

I want to select post category from drop down and show list of post belong to that category with thumbnail in wordpress

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible, or at least post what you have tried so far. This way, it's more likely users on SO can help you.

Comment: i want to display all latest posts with thumbnail,date and author name belong to specific category selected by user